# How to create an approval system for a model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I created a system for several types of users. These users are analyst, lead, manager, etc. I have a credit limit table (doa) in my system. I want to when a `lead` type user updates a field in this table it shouldn't be accepted until a `manager` approves it.

So, the old value should be valid until the `manager` approves the new values, and when the `manager` approves it the new value should be accepted. How can I do that?

Here are my codes:

**models.py**

```
class DoaTable(models.Model):
    LIMITS = (
        ('Low Risk', 'Low Risk'),
        ('Medium Risk', 'Medium Risk'),
        ('Moderately High Risk', 'Moderately High Risk'),
        ...
    )

    RANKS = (
        ('Analyst', 'Analyst'),
        ('Senior Analyst', 'Senior Analyst'),
        ('Lead', 'Lead'),
        ('Manager', 'Manager'),
        ...
        ('Chief Financial Officer', 'Chief Financial Officer'),
    )
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=RANKS)
    risk = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=LIMITS)
    limit = models.FloatField()
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
def update_limit(request, id):
    limiting = get_object_or_404(DoaTable, id=id)
    form = UpdateDoaTableForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=limiting)
    limiting_item = DoaTable.objects.filter(id=id)

    if form.is_valid():
        update_form = form.save(commit=False)
        update_form.approval = False
        update_form.save()
        return redirect('approvals:update_limit_list')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'limiting_item': limiting_item,
    }

    return render(request, 'limitUpdate.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UpdateDoaTableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DoaTable
        fields = ('limit',)
```

Comment: A new table which will contain the changes proposed by the `lead` type user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table to hold the Changes. When a manager approves, you can save the change.